# UIPinchGestureRecognizer keeping current object active in recogniser

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I haven't been able to find the answer to this question anywhere, so I thought I'd ask it and see if anyone else needs it.

I have a `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` acting on a `UILabel`, so when the user pinched it, the label scales. Now during the scale I want to add another `UILabel` on top of the other Label but remove the other label, though when I do it the UIPinchGestureRecognizer stops and I have to start the gesture again on the other Label. Is there away to allow the gesture to continue over to the other label continuously.

My current Code

```
func handleScale(recognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer)
{
    recognizer.view!.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view!.transform,recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale)

    recognizer.scale = 1

    recognizer.view!.frame = CGRectMake(recognizer.view!.frame.minX, recognizer.view!.frame.minY, recognizer.view!.frame.width, recognizer.view!.frame.height)

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed)
    {
        label.removeFromSuperview()

        self.buttonAction22(nil)

        println("button22Called")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a container view that houses both these labels, and put the gesture recognizer on the container.